# How can I move a int from xmm register to eax register?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, sse

I have to call an assembly method to calculate an addition of two integers, using sse, from C.

The simple C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int add(int a, int b);

int main(){

    int a=5;
    int b=2;
    int n = add(a,b);
    printf("%d\n",n);

    return 0;

}
```

---

While the nasm code is:

```
section .bss
    RISULTATO   resd    1

section .text

global add

add:
    ;-----------------------------------------------
    ;   start point of the function
    ;-----------------------------------------------

    push ebp    ; salva il Base Pointer
    mov ebp, esp    ; il Base Pointer punta al Record di Attivazione corrente
    push ebx    ; salva i registri da preservare
    push esi
    push edi

    ;-----------------------------------------------
    ;   add implementation
    ;-----------------------------------------------

    movss xmm0, [ebp+8]
    movss xmm1, [ebp+12]

    addss xmm1, xmm0
    movss [RISULTATO], xmm1

    mov eax, [RISULTATO]

    ;-----------------------------------------------
    ;   exit point of the function
    ;-----------------------------------------------

    pop edi     ; ripristina i registri da preservare
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp,ebp ; ripristina lo Stack Pointer
    pop ebp     ; ripristina il Base Pointer
    ret     ; ritorna alla funzione chiamante
```

---

But in this way I need to pass from RISULTATO stored in memory.
There is any way to avoid this and move directly the result stored in xmm0 to eax?

Naturally I need to move the result of the addition in eax to pass it to my C method, because the return value must to be in eax register.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: If you look at the instruction set reference, you can find the `MOVD` instruction. If you look at it some more, you might also notice that `addss` adds floats not integers. You need `PADDD` instead. The whole code can be simplified to: `MOVD xmm0, [esp+4]; MOVD xmm1, [esp+8]; PADDD xmm0, xmm1; MOVD eax, xmm0; RET`.

Comment: Or `movq` to load both values at once, then `phadd` (horizontal add).  But that's only useful because there's more data movement than computation going on.  `phadd` is much slower than `padd`.